# Collect VM uptime from openstack cloud

Tags: redhat, openstack, openstack-nova

I would like to collect uptime info from a VM provisioned in Redhat Openstack. Is there a native service in OpenStack to continually provide the system logs (with uptime info)? I checked Nova VM diagnostics capability - https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Nova_VM_Diagnostics#Overview
but i am still trying to figure out if i should have it on an agent on the VM in openstack to provide me the logs or is there any better and elegant way to do it?

Comment: Why `azure` tag is added? How is it related here? Have you tried `openstack console log show <instance-id>`? If not, you have to use `cloud-init` & override `runcmd` to check the `uptime`..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gnocchi service for information about server uptime.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of these solutions

- setup ceilometer with seprated rabbit-mq cluster
- use libvirt exporter (if you are using kvm/qemu) and prometheus.
- setup custom script and send it to instance via cloud-init (not very good idea if you are not the owner of instance)